# How to combine these 2 MySQL SELECT statements together?

Tags: mysql, sql

On my `users` table there is a column called `featured`. If it has a value of 1 then the user is featured, if 0 then not featured.

On my homepage I want to display all users on my site. But I want the featured ones to show before the non featured ones.

### Statement 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
JOIN `profiles` ON users.user_id = profiles.user_id
JOIN `geo` ON users.zip = geo.zip_code
JOIN `user_activity` ON users.user_id = user_activity.user_id
WHERE users.featured = '1'
ORDER BY users.user_id DESC
LIMIT ". ($page_num - 1) * $per_page .", ". $per_page;
```

### Statement 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
JOIN `profiles` ON users.user_id = profiles.user_id
JOIN `geo` ON users.zip = geo.zip_code
JOIN `user_activity` ON users.user_id = user_activity.user_id
WHERE users.featured != '1'
ORDER BY users.user_id DESC
LIMIT ". ($page_num - 1) * $per_page .", ". $per_page;
```

Both statements are identical except the where clause. How to merge these 2 together so featured users show first and then non featured ones.

### EDIT

I should have mentioned, I would like the result set to be returned as one collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` u
JOIN `profiles` p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
JOIN `geo` g ON u.zip = g.zip_code
JOIN `user_activity` ua ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
ORDER BY u.featured DESC,
    u.user_id DESC
LIMIT ". ($page_num - 1) * $per_page .", ". $per_page;
```

Comment: Why not simply `ORDER BY users.featured DESC`?

Comment: OP says possible values are 0 and 1, so the simpler form should work even on a text column.

Comment: I need the users to be sorted by newest to oldest. User_id is an auto increment integer field. So newer users have larger ids than older ones. That's why in my initial query I was ordering by user_id desc. Ideally I would like to order initially by featured and within featured show newest to oldest and then show non featured and order those by newest to oldest.

Comment: Modified query to remove unnecessary case.

Comment: @RedFilter Sorry, new to mysql. Just to clarify, right now your query will retrieve all featured users first and then non featured. Within both sets users will be displayed newest to oldest, correct?

Comment: @JakeRow123 Yes, but I have now modified it to sort as per requested in your comment: featured first, newest to oldest when featured, oldest to newest when not featured.

Comment: @RedFilter oh yeah sorry about that, that was a typo in my comment. I meant to to say newest to oldest both times, I edited the correction but after you must have read it.

Comment: @JakeRow123 You have me running in circles! Query restored to previous behavior.

Comment: @RedFilter thanks, sorry about that. SO answers come really fast!